# Exclude file while copying to output directory in maven

Tags: java, maven, ant

I am trying to exclude `.jar` files from getting copied to the output directory. I have tried the solutions given i.e. `<excludes>*.jar</excludes>` and `<warSourceExcludes>*.jar</warSourceExcludes>` but none of them is working.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-artifacts</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>../../ReleaseArtifacts</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>install-artifacts-2</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>../../../ReleaseArtifacts/${project.version}</outputDirectory>             
                        <excludes>*.jar</excludes>                  
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Could you post the entire plugin definition? I guess we're talking about `maven-dependency-plugin` here. Also, please specify more clearly what you want to exclude (is it a dependency, files withing a dependency...?).

Comment: As @Tunaki said, post the full plugin please.   You could try setting the scope of the artifacts to be excluded to `<scope>provided</scope>` in their dependency definitions

Comment: In the source destination I need only .war files not .jar. So want to exclude them

Comment: Are you saying the goal `copy` of `maven-dependency-plugin` is including all the transitive dependencies? Which jar do you want to exclude?

Comment: Yes, I am copying the artifacts at two separate locations, so at one particular location I only need .war file only not .jar files